# R package RSEIS - example please?

Tags: r

I have a 3D seismic cube of data I would experiment with using R.  I found the R package RSEIS which seems to load the SEG-Y file, ok using ...

```
require(RSEIS)
fn <-'My.sgy'
dt <- read1segy(fn)
```

The large (3G file) is loaded into a list with two fields "HEAD" and "Amp", which I interpret to be header and amplitude. The HEAD has 90 fields as below which I expect to contain the information about the 3D grid somewhere - but I'm not sure how to interpret these - each has a single integer value

```
> names(dt$HEAD)
 [1] "lineSeq"                "reelSeq"                "event_number"          
 [4] "channel_number"         "energySourcePt"         "cdpEns"                
 [7] "traceInEnsemble"        "traceID"                "vertSum"               
[10] "horSum"                 "dataUse"                "sourceToRecDist"       
[13] "recElevation"           "sourceSurfaceElevation" "sourceDepth"           
[16] "datumElevRec"           "datumElevSource"        "sourceWaterDepth"      
[19] "recWaterDepth"          "elevationScale"         "coordScale"            
[22] "sourceLongOrX"          "sourceLatOrY"           "recLongOrX"            
[25] "recLatOrY"              "coordUnits"             "weatheringVelocity"    
[28] "subWeatheringVelocity"  "sourceUpholeTime"       "recUpholeTime"         
[31] "sourceStaticCor"        "recStaticCor"           "totalStatic"           
[34] "lagTimeA"               "lagTimeB"               "delay"                 
[37] "muteStart"              "muteEnd"                "sampleLength"          
[40] "deltaSample"            "gainType"               "gainConst"             
[43] "initialGain"            "correlated"             "sweepStart"            
[46] "sweepEnd"               "sweepLength"            "sweepType"             
[49] "sweepTaperAtStart"      "sweepTaperAtEnd"        "taperType"             
[52] "aliasFreq"              "aliasSlope"             "notchFreq"             
[55] "notchSlope"             "lowCutFreq"             "hiCutFreq"             
[58] "lowCutSlope"            "hiCutSlope"             "year"                  
[61] "day"                    "hour"                   "minute"                
[64] "second"                 "timeBasisCode"          "traceWeightingFactor"  
[67] "phoneRollPos1"          "phoneFirstTrace"        "phoneLastTrace"        
[70] "gapSize"                "taperOvertravel"        "station_name"          
[73] "sensor_serial"          "channel_name"           "totalStaticHi"         
[76] "samp_rate"              "data_form"              "m_secs"                
[79] "trigyear"               "trigday"                "trighour"              
[82] "trigminute"             "trigsecond"             "trigmills"             
[85] "scale_fac"              "inst_no"                "not_to_be_used"        
[88] "num_samps"              "max"                    "min"
```

The field "AMP" contains 781 million large integer values which I expect need to be converted back to a decimal precision using one of the header values

```
$ amp : int [1:781504584] 1089794243 -1042038332 -672603328 -700417339 -19876061
```

So there are two questions for those who may be familiar with SEG_Y format

1. What header values should I be using to interpret the origin, spacing and number of nodes for this 3D seismic data?
2. What header value control the reading of the precision of the "amp" amplitude fields?

For those who may be familiar with the RSEIS package - an example of how to display section or plan of the data would be helpful.